# Switch between two versions of Gnome shell

Tags: gnome

In my Ubuntu 18.04.2 Machine i have GNOME shell 3.28 by default. I installed GNOME shell 3.30 snap package using command:

```
snap install --edge gnome-3-30-1804
```

But my GNOME version isn't changed to 3.30 it is still 3.28. What to do now? How can I switch versions?

Comment: AFAIK that snap package is not a shell but contains some sort of base libraries.

Comment: I also suspect it wouldn't have write access to your file-system.  I don't see a `--classic` to bypass strict confinement in your command; it may also require `--dangerous` to be fully useful as you would like  https://blog.ubuntu.com/2017/01/09/how-to-snap-introducing-classic-confinement.  I suspect @Kulfy is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, no, you cannot run a newer Gnome Shell version through snap.

The snap you install contains core library files. It is intended to run the latest Gnome apps such as Fotos, Maps, System Monitor, Calculator on an older Gnome Shell using snap technology. In fact, in Ubuntu, System Monitor and Calculator by default come as a snap app.